# Programmatically deleting a filefield content and the associated file?

Tags: 7, files

If I do the usual

```
unset($node->myfilefield["und"][0]);
```

Would that take care of the actual deletion of the file as well on node_save?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You should use [`file_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7). The function will remove the attached file from the database and from the disk.

```
// Load the node.
$node = node_load('1');
// Get the language for the file field.
$lang = field_language('node', $node, 'myfilefield');
// load the file
$file = file_load($node->myfilefield[$lang][0]['fid']);
// unset the field for the node
unset($node->myfilefield[$lang][0]);
// delete file from disk and from database
file_delete($file);
// Save the node.
node_save($node);
```

The `file_delete()` also takes a second argument `$force` that if set to `TRUE` will remove the file even if it's reported as in use by the `file_usage` table.

Comment: Suppose before saving $node I set $node->revision =1 then in this case will the attachment still be deleted?

Comment: @Aga - I guess so, if the file was attached to that revision. But, the best way would be to just try it and see how it works.

Comment: I've tried it and it won't delete it.

Comment: @Aga - Was the file attached to an earlier revision? In that case I don't think it would be deleted. I will try it when I get a chance.

Comment: @Aga - I managed to delete the file from a revision by setting the `$force` parameter to `TRUE` in my call to `file_delete()`.

Comment: In my case file is getting deleted but node doesn't get updated after node_save. I have multiple values in image field. The one image field file I want to delete get's deleted but node update is not hapua URL andpening, I have to go to form the form and click save.

Comment: @ruby - I think this could be because there is multiple images and you must use an array like: `$node->file['und'][0][0]['fid']` instead? Try checking how the data looks like.

Comment: I figured out the problem was after we unset a value, since it is a multi valued field we must reset the array. hence after resetting we should use '$node->file['und'] = array_values($node->file['und'])'. And it works!

Comment: Will it delete its associated image styles files stored in those individual directories or just the default image.

Comment: the generated imagestyles is not stored in the same directory. they are stored under a cache folder i.e sites/default/files/styles/<style>

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily call file_delete(), enough:

```
unset($node->myfilefield["und"][0]);
node_save($node);
```

Comment: That will only remove the relation between the `file_managed` table and your custom image field. It won't remove the file from disk nor will it remove the record in the `file_managed` table, but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I checked. File removed from db and filesystem.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work for me.